# Calculating Composition of 2 Functions

Tags: real-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ and $g:  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose $g(0) = (1,2)$, $g'(0) = (-1,4)$ and $(f \circ g)'(0) = -3 $.

Furthermore $\displaystyle \frac{df}{dx}(1,2) = \frac{df}{dy}(1,2)$.

> Compute the value of $\displaystyle\frac{df}{dx}(1,2)$

I have used the property that $(f \circ g)'(0) = f' (g(0))* g'(0)$ so I have that $f'(1,2) * (-1,4)$ but I do not know how to compute $f'(1,2)$.

Comment: Please add your own attempt at solving this problem and do so by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are
$$
(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) \\
(f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))(g'(x))\\
$$
we have
$$
\frac{df}{dx}(1,2) = \frac{df}{dy}(1,2) = \xi,\qquad g(0) = (1,2), \qquad g'(0) = (-1,4), \qquad (f \circ g)'(0) = -3
$$
\begin{align}
-3 &= (f \circ g)'(0) = f'(g(0))(g'(0))\\ 
&= f'(\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix})(\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\end{pmatrix}) \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}\xi & \xi\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\end{pmatrix}\\
-3&= -\xi+4\xi = 3\xi \implies \xi = -1 = \frac{df}{dx}(1,2) = \frac{df}{dy}(1,2)
\end{align}
That is
$$
f'(1,2) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$